# AVFoundation: Adding silence pause between playback loops

Tags: ios, xcode, avfoundation, avaudioplayer

I want to loop a recorded sound 3 times, but want one second of silence between loops, how can I go about this? My code for play_button:

```
-(IBAction) play_button_pressed{

AVAudioPlayer * avPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:recordedTmpFile error:&error];

[avPlayer setNumberOfLoops: 2];
[avPlayer play];

}
```

1) Anything I can add to this method to add this one second of silence?

2) If not, is there any way to add a second of silence to the actual recording?

**EDIT:** Thanks; I have gotten a solution that repeats the sound one time with a pause of 2 seconds; it does not loop infinitely though, can you tell what I am missing?

```
-(IBAction) play_button_pressed{

AVAudioPlayer * avPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:recordedTmpFile error:&error];

//[avPlayer setNumberOfLoops: 2];
avPlayer.delegate = self;
[avPlayer prepareToPlay];
[avPlayer play];

}

- (void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)avPlayer successfully:(BOOL)flag
{
NSLog(@"audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying");
tm = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0
                                 target:self
                               selector:@selector(waitedtoplay)
                               userInfo:nil 
                                repeats:NO];
}

-(void) waitedtoplay
{
    AVAudioPlayer * avPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:recordedTmpFile error:&error];
[tm invalidate];
[avPlayer prepareToPlay];
[avPlayer play];
NSLog(@"waitedtoplay");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, no method of AVAudioPlayer makes "silence" between the play loop.

When I made same kind of loop, I utilized call-back method defined in AVAudioPlayerDelegate and timer.

In the header file, declare to use AVAudioPlayerDelegate as follows;

```
@interface xxxxController : UIViewController
<AVAudioPlayerDelegate>{
```

When avPlayer ends to play the sound,
the method "audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying" will be called.

Then call method to wait certain period of time, for example;

```
-(void) wait{
float seconds = 2.0f;
tm = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:seconds
                                      target:self
                                    selector:@selector(waitedtoplay) 
                                    userInfo:nil 
                                     repeats:NO];
}
```

And, in the method "waitedtoplay", call next [avPlayer play]

```
-(void) waitedtoplay{
    [tm invalidate];
    [avPlayer play];
}
```

This is a never-ending loop, so please add counter to limit the number of loop = 3.

EDIT

In the method you added as "waitedtoplay", you missed to set "avplayer.delegate = self".
So, AVAudioPlayer will not call "audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying".

```
-(void) waitedtoplay
{
AVAudioPlayer * avPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:recordedTmpFile error:&error];
[tm invalidate];
avPlayer.delegate = self; <<=== MISSING !
[avPlayer prepareToPlay];
[avPlayer play];
NSLog(@"waitedtoplay");
}
```

Please add it as above, and it will repeat infinitely...